# End of Media Trigger (Iframe)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe, video

I'm looking for a way to determine when an embedded video is done playing. I know the following works for media elements (e.g.  ), however it doesn't fire for an iframe, even though media is embedded.

```
$("#myVideo").on("ended", function() {});
```

Is there a way to have the same functionality as the above for a video embedded as an Iframe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason the trigger won't fire is because it cant be selected. Security features don't allow you to access Dom content inside an embedded document.

You will need to use the  tag.

To do this with YouTube videos, use the [mediaElement.js](http://mediaelementjs.com) library. The triggers can be used through that application.